# Angularjs Get Json from url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

First time trying to get json data and show it to my app using AngularJS, does not show any data,  this is my code implemented

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>

    <td>{{ x.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.title }}</td>

</table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://example.com/api/get_page_index/")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.pages;});
});
</script>
```

**Json content from url**

```
 {
      "status": "ok",
      "pages": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "type": "page",
          "slug": "sample-page",
          "url": "http:\/\/example.com\/",
          "status": "publish",
          "title": "example page",
          "content": "",
          "excerpt": "",
          "date": false,
          "modified": "2016-08-09 17:28:01",
          "comments": [],
          "attachments": [],
          },
```

Comment: First, are there any errors in your console? Second, what **exactly** do you want the result to look like?

Comment: no error on my console, i want display the results from all json file id and title

Comment: @Max did you check the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this,

```
 <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="(header, value) in results[0]">
          {{header}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in results">
        <td ng-repeat="cell in row">
          {{cell}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

[`WORKING DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/rgsob1htk5jd8NKuaZCk?p=preview)

Comment: it works, but It returns all the result of json. I just want the result of the title and the id from json

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan, yes it works thanks!!! i have a questions if want to access to "author" from json and its children elements "name" what would be the right way?

       ` 

"author": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "admin",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "url": "",
        "description": ""
       }, `

Comment: `"pages": [
      {
       "id": 2,
       "author": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "admin",
          "first_name": "",
          "last_name": "",
          "url": "",
          "description": ""
         },`